# How to implement the new facebook widget on lockscreen

Tags: android, facebook, layout, lockscreen

I want to make a widget like the new widget facebook just released.
What I need is a small layout with buttons to be visible on the lockscreen and receive touch events.

When I am use`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` I can see the layout on top of the lockscreen but then it's not getting any touch events.
This is my code:

```
final int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
            | PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, flags, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
```

What am I doing wrong, Should I not use the window for this? How do you guys think facebook managed to pull this one off?
Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I mean...I need it to be on top of the main lock screen... not at the side. Just like it shows in the link I attached